# Why doesn't the entire user input get stored into an element of the array?

Tags: java

Let's say I have something like this

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println("How are you?");
scan.next();
a.add(scan.next());
```

Then the user inputs

```
good, and you?
```

For some reason, only the last word will be put into my array. How can I get the entire phrase (good, and you?) to be put into my array as one element?

Comment: Use `scan.nextLine()`.  And call it just once, not twice.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much!